# How to fix Bad request in ScriptRunner - jira

Tags: java, groovy, jira

I have been browsing topics for a long time but I can't find answer for my problem.

I am trying to do integration between two jira.

When I try this JSON on postman or SoapUI it's OK, but in testRunner I have ERROR

It's my code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
import groovy.json.StreamingJsonBuilder;
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager;
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils

def log = Logger.getLogger("com.acme.CreateSubtask")
log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)

log.debug "dey3"

def baseURL = "https://MYJIRA/rest/api/2/issue/";




def body_req = """

{ "fields":
{
"project": {"key": "JIRA"}, 
"issuetype": {"name": "Task"},
"summary": "My Issue.",
"description": "Test"
}
}

"""


def basicAuth = "ZzzzzzzzzzzZZZZZZz"
URL url = new URL(baseURL);
HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization","Basic "+ "ZzzzzzzzzzzZZZZZZz");
connection.requestMethod = "POST";
connection.setDoInput(true); 
connection.setDoOutput(true); 
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
connection.outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8") { new StreamingJsonBuilder(it, body_req) }

connection.connect();

log.debug HttpURLConnection
log.debug body_req
log.debug (connection.getResponseMessage())
log.debug "Content:"
log.debug connection.getContent()
log.debug (connection.getResponseMessage())
log.debug (connection.getRequestProperties())

log.debug "dey4"
```

In logs:

```
at Script807.run(Script807.groovy:50)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://MYJIRA/rest/api/2/issue/
at Script807.run(Script807.groovy:52)
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: https://MYJIRA/rest/api/2/issue/
2019-06-26 09:45:58,729 http-bio-443-exec-18 ERROR jira 585x33522x1 78fcwl 10.250.112.135 /secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa [scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction] Script function failed on issue: HD-113062, actionId: 601, file: <inline script>
2019-06-26 09:45:58,729 http-bio-443-exec-18 ERROR jira  585x33522x1 78fcwl 10.250.112.135 /secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa [scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction] *************************************************************************************
2019-06-26 09:45:58,727 http-bio-443-exec-18 DEBUG jira  585x33522x1 78fcwl 10.250.112.135 /secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa [com.acme.CreateSubtask] Content:
2019-06-26 09:45:58,727 http-bio-443-exec-18 DEBUG jira  585x33522x1 78fcwl 10.250.112.135 /secure/WorkflowUIDispatcher.jspa [com.acme.CreateSubtask] Bad Request
2019-06-26 09:45:58,726 http-bio-443-exec-9 DEBUG jira 585x33523x2 1g0o53j 10.250.8.21 /rest/api/2/issue/ [anguswarren.jira.RemoteUserJiraAuth] Session found; user already logged in
2019-06-26 09:45:58,725 http-bio-443-exec-9 DEBUG jira 585x33523x2 1g0o53j 10.250.8.21 /rest/api/2/issue/ [anguswarren.jira.RemoteUserJiraAuth] Session found; user already logged in
2019-06-26 09:45:58,725 http-bio-443-exec-9 DEBUG jira 585x33523x2 1g0o53j 10.250.8.21 /rest/api/2/issue/ [anguswarren.jira.RemoteUserJiraAuth] Session found; user already logged in
2019-06-26 09:45:58,725 http-bio-443-exec-9 DEBUG jira 585x33523x2 - 10.250.8.21 /rest/api/2/issue/ [anguswarren.jira.RemoteUserJiraAuth] Session found; user already logged in

}
}
"description": "Test"
"summary": "My Issue.",
"issuetype": {"name": "Task"},
"project": {"key": "JIRA"}, 
{
{ "fields":
```

The body_req has correct format?
I have no idea what is wrong with this. I couldnt find anserws anywhere :(

Regards

Comment: Hello Marek. Welcome to StackOverflow. In your log there is a `Bad Request` request message. That usually means that Jira got your message but something is missing. You can generate "code" in Postman. Maybe you should let Postman create "code" of type "HTTP" and have a look if your Postman request contains data that is missing from your Groovy script.

Comment: how can I check the entire request on jira? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better define payload programmatically and then convert it to json. Just for avoid escape exceptions or forgotten bracers or anything else. Try define your payload like this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def createIssueRequest = new Expando()
createIssueRequest.fields = new Expando(summary: "My Issue.", description: "Test")
createIssueRequest.fields.project = new Expando(key: "JIRA")
createIssueRequest.fields.issuetype = new Expando(name: "Task")
def createIssueJson = JsonOutput.toJson(createIssueRequest)
...
...
...
connection.outputStream.withWriter("UTF-8") { new StreamingJsonBuilder(it, createIssueJson) }
```